# None of my commands are running on discord.py and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, discord.py, command

I'm new to discord.py and I'm trying to make a music bot for me and my friends, I've probably made a dumb mistake and sorry if I have, I don't know what is the cause; could you please help. I'm using the *hikari*, *discord* and *youtube_dl* libraries If that helps. Also this is just one command if you want to see more of the code please ask.

```
import hikari
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, bot):
       self.bot = bot

       self.is_playing = False
       self.is_paused = False


       self.music_queue = []
       self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
       self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

       self.vc = None

def search_yt(self, item):
   with YoutubeDl(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
       try:
           info = ydl.extract_info('ytsearch:%s' % item, download=false)['entries'][0]
       except Exception:
           return False
   return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}
   
   def play_next(self):
       if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
           self.is_playing = True
           
           m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

           self.music_queue.pop(0)

           self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self_play())
       else:
           self.is_playing = False

   async def play_music(self, ctx):
       if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
           self.is_playing = True
           m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

           if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
               self.vc = await self.musoc_queue[0][1].connect()

               if self.vc == None:
                   await ctx.send('could not connect to the voice channel, sorry Blooketeers')
                   return
           else:
               await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

           self.music_queue.pop(0)

           self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())

       else:
           self.is_playing = False

   @commands.command(name='play', aliases=['p', 'playing'], help='play the selected song chosen by the Blooketeers!')
   async def play(self, ctx, *args):
       query =' '.join(args)

       voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
       if voice_channel is None:
           await ctx.send('connect to a voice channel blooketeers!')
       elif self.is_paused:
           self.vc.resume()
       else:
           song = self.search_yt(query)
           if type(song) == type(True):
               await ctx.send('Sorry Blooketeers, I couldn\'t download the song. Incorrect format, try a different keyword.')
           else:
               await ctx.send('Song added to the queue Blooketeers! Happy listening!')
               self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

               if self.is_playing == False:
                   await self.play_music(ctx)
   @commands.command(name='pause', help='Pauses the current song chosen by the Blooketeers!')
   async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
       if self.is_playing:
           self.is_playing = False
           self.is_paused = True
           self.vc.pause()
       elif self.is_paused:
           self.is_playing = True
           self.is_paused = False
           self.vc.resume()
           

   @commands.command(name='resume', aliases=['r'], help='Resumes the current song chosen by the Blooketeers!')
   async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
       if self.is_paused:
           self.is_playing = True
           self.is_paused = False
           self.vc.resume()

   @commands.command(name='skip', aliases=['s'], help = 'Skips the current song chosen by the blooketeers!')
   async def skip(self, ctx, *args):
       if self.vc != None and self.vc:
           self.vc.stop()
           await self.play_music(ctx)

   @commands.command(name='queue', aliases=['q'], help='Displays all the songs currently in the queue Blooketeers!')
   async def queue(self, ctx):
       retval = ''

       for i in range(0, len(slef.music_queue)):
           if i > 4: break
           retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + '\n'

       if retval != '':
           await ctx.send(retval)
       else:
           await ctx.send('No music in the queue Blooketeers, go add some!')

       @commands.command(name='clear', aliases=['c', 'bin'], help='Stop the current song and clears the current queue Blooketeers"')
       async def clear(self, ctx, *args):
           if slef.vc != None and self.is_playing:
               self.vc.stop()
           self.music_queue = []
           await ctx.send('All the music is cleared Blooketeers, go add some more!')

   @commands.command(name='leave', aliases=['disconnect', 'l', 'd'], help='Kicks the bot from the voice channel Blooketeers!')
   async def leave(self, ctx):
       self.is_playing = False
       self.is_paused = False
       await self.vc.disconnect()
```

```
import hikari
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

from help_cog import help_cog 
from music_cog import music_cog

intents=discord.Intents().all()

bot = hikari.GatewayBot(token='tokenwashere')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

bot.remove_command('help')

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
    await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot.run('tokenwashere')
```

Comment: Is there an error message when executing the commands? Can you post those as well as more of your code?

Comment: Hello. I see you are declaring an async function, but is it linked to a command ? 

Discord bots work with events or commands. Or you declare it's an event with @bot.events or it's a command with @bot.command(name_of_command). Could you share more of your code so we could see the declaration of your bot and stuff ?

Comment: I've updated it to show the whole script I hope that helped @pluckplk

Comment: Is the indentation of the `search_yt` function correct? Are you adding this cog to the bot?

Comment: I'm not totally sure but I think it is as I can't think what else it could be but that could me being dumb but do you mean that ``` @commands.command()
                                                                                  
  async def ``` because what else would it be?

Comment: I see a few issues. I never played yet with youtube integration, but my first problem with your code is that you don't instanciate your bot. You wish `from dicord.ext import commands`, yes, then you need to declare intents of your bot with `intents=discord.Intents().all()` (or .default(), depends of what you need to with the bot. Then, you instanciate the bot with `bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)` so your bot looks for any command starting with "!". Finally, you wish to assign function to a command, like `@bot.command(name='play')` followed by `async def play(..)`

Comment: Are you doing `await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))` anywhere. I assume you've split your cog code and main bot.py file.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is helping because i'm generally quite new to discord bots and thx for that and yes I have split my code over multiple files

Comment: also, in your clear command, you have a "slef" instead of "self". Does your code produce any error that we could look at to check where issue is, or your code doesn't run at all ? (and so you should modify as previously stated)

Comment: my code runs but the bot is online but it just isn't responding to commands and it just says iscord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found @pl

Comment: modify the code as I told so you should at least produce something with the "!play" option, even if it is an error. Right now, your code runs but never gets called coz you haven't defined what your bot can read and at which command to react. Since you have to react to members messages, you should also activate intents in your discord portal.

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/applications/ You'll have a "bot" section on the left. You scroll down to "Privileged Gatewatays Intents" and you have to enable the ones you'll use. You can find all these in the docs, aswell as other possible options to Intents (like the Intents.Default() ), depending of what your bot will do (in your case, at least reading members messages). https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: I added the other .py file to show what is happening over on that one maybe it's to do with something in that file and I've corrected the other mistakes but it's still not working @pluckplk

Comment: Okay. I didn't know about Hikari so I just checked a tuto about, and I see a few other issues right now. For more structure, I'll publish my modifications to your code as an answer, but it won't be a definitive one. Our idea right now is that you can type your command and receive interactions/errors to continue the exploration of your topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import hikari
# also import lightbulb, that works with hikari
import lightbulb
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from help_cog import help_cog 
from music_cog import music_cog

# intents : or you pick default(), or you pick all()
# but you have to modify your bot Gateways intents in discord portal accordingly
# since .all() requires to aknowledge all intents possible. 

intents=discord.Intents.all()

# now you want to define your token here, before passing it
# assuming you have a file ".env" in the same folder as your application

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

# then you create your bot. Lightbulb is going deeper than hikari 
#since you can configure the command prefix aswell so.. 
# bot = hikari.GatewayBot(token=TOKEN, intents=intents)
# turns into : 
bot = lightbulb.BotApp(token=TOKEN, intents=intents, prefix="!")
bot.remove_command('help')

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
    await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))

bot.run()
#token isn't needed here since you use hikari/lightbulb that manages it
```

In the other file it should go this way :

```
import hikari
import lightbulb
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, bot):
       self.bot = bot

       self.is_playing = False
       self.is_paused = False


       self.music_queue = []
       self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
       self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

       self.vc = None

def search_yt(self, item):
   with YoutubeDl(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
       try:
           info = ydl.extract_info('ytsearch:%s' % item, download=false)['entries'][0]
       except Exception:
           return False
   return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}
   
   def play_next(self):
       if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
           self.is_playing = True
           
           m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

           self.music_queue.pop(0)

           self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self_play())
       else:
           self.is_playing = False

   async def play_music(self, ctx):
       if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
           self.is_playing = True
           m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

           if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
               self.vc = await self.musoc_queue[0][1].connect()

               if self.vc == None:
                   await ctx.send('could not connect to the voice channel, sorry Blooketeers')
                   return
           else:
               await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

           self.music_queue.pop(0)

           self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())

       else:
           self.is_playing = False

# here, it's not commands.command but bot.command
# but we also want lightbulb to take over this, so we remove overwrite
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("play", description="play the selected song chosen by the Blooketeers!")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
   async def play(self, ctx: lightbulb.Context, *args):
       query =' '.join(args)

       voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
       if voice_channel is None:
           await ctx.send('connect to a voice channel blooketeers!')
       elif self.is_paused:
           self.vc.resume()
       else:
           song = self.search_yt(query)
           if type(song) == type(True):
               await ctx.send('Sorry Blooketeers, I couldn\'t download the song. Incorrect format, try a different keyword.')
           else:
               await ctx.send('Song added to the queue Blooketeers! Happy listening!')
               self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

               if self.is_playing == False:
                   await self.play_music(ctx)
# here too 
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("pause", description="Pauses the current song chosen by the Blooketeers!")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def pause(self, ctx: lightbulb.Context, *args):
       if self.is_playing:
           self.is_playing = False
           self.is_paused = True
           self.vc.pause()
       elif self.is_paused:
           self.is_playing = True
           self.is_paused = False
           self.vc.resume()
           
# and here 
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("resume", description="Resumes the current song chosen by the Blooketeers!")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def resume(self, ctx: lightbulb.Context, *args):
       if self.is_paused:
           self.is_playing = True
           self.is_paused = False
           self.vc.resume()

# and here 
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("skip", description="Skips the current song chosen by the blooketeers!")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def skip(self, ctx: lightbulb.Context, *args):
       if self.vc != None and self.vc:
           self.vc.stop()
           await self.play_music(ctx)
# and here 
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("queue", description="Displays all the songs currently in the queue Blooketeers!")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def queue(self, ctx: lightbulb.Context):
       retval = ''

       for i in range(0, len(slef.music_queue)):
           if i > 4: break
           retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + '\n'

       if retval != '':
           await ctx.send(retval)
       else:
           await ctx.send('No music in the queue Blooketeers, go add some!')

# and here 
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("clear", description="Stop the current song and clears the current queue Blooketeers")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)

async def clear(self, ctx: lightbulb.Context, *args):
           if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
               self.vc.stop()
           self.music_queue = []
           await ctx.send('All the music is cleared Blooketeers, go add some more!')

# and finally here
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("leave", description="Kicks the bot from the voice channel Blooketeers!")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
   async def leave(self, ctx: lightbulb.Context):
       self.is_playing = False
       self.is_paused = False
       await self.vc.disconnect()
```

I am not completely sure it will work, as said in previous comments, I never used hikari/lightbulb, but following their doc, it seems to be the way. I've added comments where I changed/added items.

Comment: You may wish to also consult this doc, with an example of how to use hikari and how to use lightbulb, that offers a deep configuration of your bot when you create each function. 
https://novanai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lightbulb/part_2.html

Comment: sorry for the late reply but now the bot isn't booting and the console says this ``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Desktop\DiscordBot\bot.py", line 6, in <module>
    from help_cog import help_cog 
  File "C:\Desktop\DiscordBot\help_cog.py", line 4, in <module>
    class help_cog(commands.Cog):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\DiscordBot\help_cog.py", line 33, in help_cog
    @bot.command(name='help', help='Displays all the avalable commands to help out all of you blooketeers!')
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined ``` and the bot wont boot @pluckplk srry for the late reply

Comment: Hey, we all have a life :). As I'm reading it, there is an issue with `help_cog.py` on your command `help`. If there is only the help in the file, maybe copy it in the `music_cog.py` ? Else, you'll have to declare again lightbulb, etc, but I'm not sure it won't bug since you would declare the bot in two files.